# Using Divergence theorem to calculate integral

Tags: divergence-operator

**Question:**
Use Divergence Theorem to compute
$\int \int_D^\ (F.n) dS$ where S is bounded by $z=4-x^2-y^2$, z=0 and z=1, and the force field is $F = (z^3,x^2y,y^2z)$

**Attempt to solve:** $$div(F) =x^2+y^2 $$ 
Using cylindrical coordinates
$\int \int_D^\ (F.n) dS=\int\int\int_D div(F) dV$
$=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^2\int_0^{4-r^2}(z^2r)\,dz\,dr\,d\theta=\frac{32}{3}\pi $ 
However, the correct answer is 1. What am I doing wrong? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Your integration domain on the plane $\;z=0\;$ is the annulus between $\;x^2+y^2=3\;$ and $\;x^2+y^2=4\;$ . Where does that $\;z^2\;$ in the integrand come from? I understand the $\;r\;$ there is the Jacobian for cyl. coordinates...and are you sure the answer is $\;1\;$ ?

Comment: I was thinking $$div(F)=x^2+y^2=r^2$$. Yes the study guide says that the answer is 1. Confirmed with the professor as well.

Comment: Thanks. I just don't get anything even close to that. Anyway, check your integration domain, as said above. Besides, using cylindrical coordinates, which seems correct in this case, makes almost sure $\;\pi\;$ will appear in the final result...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct setting for the integral should be

$$=\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta\int_0^1 dz \int_0^{\sqrt{4-z}}r^3\,dr$$

indeed

- $z$ varies from 0 to 1
- for $z$ fixed, $r$ varies from 0 to $\sqrt{4-z}$
- the divegence is $r^2$

Comment: This makes sense. I got $$9\pi$$. But not 1. @gimusi , did you get the same answer? It's still not 1 and I am thinking may be the study guide had the wrong answer.

Comment: @nova_star I didn't check the result but only the set up, I verify now!

Comment: @nova_star here the solution by wolfy https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+r%5E3+dr+dz+dt+t%3D0..2pi,+z%3D0..1,r%3D0..(4-z)%5E.5

Comment: I' m pretty sure by the set up ano no one noted mistakes up to now, anyway 1 is pretty strange as result since I think that $\pi$ should appear in the solution. Maybe there is a typo in the guide.